# Move columns to rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to add the third column to the first column (my desire is that the first column will include also the third column)

Current status:

[image: Current Status]

Desired Results:

[image: desire]

Comment: I would advice to include any code you have tried into your question.
You will increase the chances to receive help and decrease the chances to have your question flagged and removed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want `UNION ALL` :

```
SELECT t.entity, t.activity
FROM table t
UNION ALL
SELECT t.entity2, t.activity2
FROM table t;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a lot of data, you may not want to scan the table multiple times -- which is what `union all` does.

Instead:

```
select (case when n.n = 1 then entity
             when n.n = 2 then entity_2
        end) as entity,
       (case when n.n = 1 then activity
             when n.n = 2 then activity_2
        end) as activity
from t cross join
     (select 1 as n from dual union all
      select 2 as n from dual
     ) n;
```

In Oracle 12C+, this is simplified using lateral joins:

```
select t.entity, s.activity
from t cross join lateral
     (select t.entity, t.activity from dual union all
      select t.entity_2, t.activity_2 from dual 
     ) s;
```

Comment: Curiosity killed the cat; I created a table with 40018 rows, and the `union all` answer took 1.52 seconds, 579 consistent gets, your first `cross join` example did a  MERGE JOIN CARTESIAN but took just 1.13 seconds and 99 gets, and the `cross join lateral` did an in-line view, 1.41 seconds, 480 gets!

Comment: @MarkStewart . . . Wow!  Interesting.  Oracle did not do a good job implementing lateral joins.

Answer (score 1):

```
select entity, activity from <table>
union all
select entity_2, activity_2 from <table>
```

Answer (score 0):

in general:

```
select col1,col2 from table1
union all
select col3,col4 form table1;
```